# How do you turn an element into an ms ajax object?

Tags: asp.net-ajax

I have an element that I get with

```
$get(myId).children[0]
```

I want to turn that element into an ms ajax object but

```
$get($get(myId).children[0])
```

Doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$get only finds an element.   If you have an element that represents the AJAX control, use $find, which takes the ID of the control as the param, as in:

```
$find("MyControlClientID")
```

So you'd want to do:

```
$find($get(myId).children[0].ClientID)
```

If the first child is the AJAX control UI element.